# Upgrading from 2.1.4 to latest version

Tags: upgrade, magento-2.1.4, version

I have Magento 2.1.4 CE installed. I have browsed the devdocs and forums on upgrading and I am confused.

What commands do I have to run exactly to do the upgrade? When I try to run

composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.7 --no-update

it asks for username/and pass but I do not have one. I downloaded the 2.1.4 archive from Magento docs.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Create an account from here](https://account.magento.com/applications/customer/login/)

**Enter email id and password if you have create an account else you have to click New Users Register button.**

After login with your magento account,

Now click on

> Marketplace -> My Products -> Access Keys

Now Go to Magento 2 Tab section,
Click button on Create a New Access key.
Enter any name and Press Ok.
Now your public and private key are generated.

```
Public key is your username
private key is your password.
```